# Try Confirm Cancel (TCC) Protocol

Tags: transaction, distributed-transactions

### My Confusion

I have been reading up about the Try Confirm Cancel (TCC) Protocol, and I understand the main idea behind it (for the happy flow). My confusion comes in how do we actually implement or manage this in the edge cases (when a service unexpectedly crashes).

Suppose we have 3 microservices: S1, S2, S3. Suppose S1 and S2 provide the TCC interface as APIs, while S3 is the service which actually calls S1 and S2 and manages the transaction. Assuming `T` to represent time, I have listed some scenarios below which seem to be problematic:

```
Scenario 1
T0: Client calls S3 to trigger a flow which uses TCC.
T1: S3 calls TRY for S1. This succeeds.
T2: S3 crashes
```

In Scenario 1 above, when S3 recovers from the crash, how will it know to call CANCEL for S1?

Another Scenario which faces the same issue:

```
Scenario 2
T0: Client calls S3 to trigger a flow which uses TCC.
T1: S3 calls TRY for S1 and S2. This succeeds.
T2: S3 calls CONFIRM for S1
T2: S3 crashes
```

In Scenario 2 above, when S3 recovers from the crash, how will it know to call CONFIRM for S2?

The articles I've read on TCC never seem to address the issues highlighted above.

### My Proposed Solution

I was thinking the only way to solve this is to somehow store a representation of the transaction that is supposed to take place. Taking the same example above, suppose S3 is a microservice trying to coordinate the transfer of money between 2 different banks S1 and S2. The flow would be something like this:

- T0: Client calls S3 to trigger transfer of money between 2 bank accounts.
- T1: S3 stores a record in DB first before making any calls to S1 and S2 (the `status` field will change according to which stage the TCC is in):

| from_user_id | to_user_id | amount | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 101 | 56 | TO_TRY |

- T2: S3 calls TRY for S1 and S2.
- T3: If both TRY succeeds, S3 should update the `status` field of the DB record to `TO_CONFIRM`. If either TRY fails, S3 should update the `status` field of the DB record to `TO_CANCEL`. Lets assume the cancellation scenario:

| from_user_id | to_user_id | amount | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 101 | 56 | TO_CANCEL |

- T4: S3 calls CANCEL for S1 and S2.
- T5: If both CANCEL succeeds, S3 should update the `status` field of the DB record to `COMPLETED`. Otherwise, just leave it in `TO_CANCEL`.

The idea behind this solution is that if S3 crashes at some point, we can have a cronjob to pick up the records in the DB that are stuck in non-COMPLETED statuses, and try to push them to the COMPLETED status (making sure that either the TRY, CANCEL or CONFIRM phase eventually follows through).

Is my proposed solution a legitimate solution? I'm assuming there are already existing solutions to this, but I can't seem to find anything on this issue. Any useful articles or resources would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate tasks involved.  One is to create the reservations by collecting a list of URIs representing the reservations.  How the initiator does this is implementation dependent.  Typically the initiator then asks a transaction coordinator to either confirm or cancel all the reservations.  As reservations have timeouts, if a participant becomes unreachable for a period of time, it will release its reservations when the timeout occurs.  The transaction coordinator will ensure that all participants are confirmed or cancelled as it can repeatedly try the PUT (confirm) or DELETE (cancel) until it gets a response or times out.

Now the coordinator in this case could be part of the initiating application, but often it's delegated to a dedicated transaction coordinator that handles all the various timeouts and failures.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).